# Proving LHS and RHS

Tags: logic

I just came across this problem from proving an equality for combinatorics. In general if I ask you to prove

> Prove that
>
> Expression X = Expression Y

Normally wouldn't one read from left to right and start showing the left is equal to the right?

Then I thought of Euclid's elements and the definition of the equality and I thought wouldn't it be the same if i prove Expression Y = Expression X? Or would that be, by *human* (or western, because I know some cultures read from right to left) convention, considered "circular logic" because I am assuming the truth of the statement and only showing the result?

Comment: Yes. Something like prove that $x = 1 \cdot x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: I would do whatever seems most convenient and works. If it’s a matter of algebraic manipulation, this might be manipulating the lefthand side into the righthand side, but it might also be manipulating the righthand side into the lefthand side or manipulating both sides until they meet in the middle. In some cases I might even assume that the two expressions are not equal and somehow derive a contradiction.